# Why does my test not work when splitting mocking and stubbing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, groovy, spock

I struggle with Spock/Groovy testing.
Don't know why but in WHEN section, I cannot check number of calls and checking the value at once..
If I check one of them separatly all works fine!

This test passed:

```java
def "should throw AppointmentNotFoundException when appointment do not exist" () {
  given:
  long nonExistingAppointmentId = 69L

  when:
  appointmentRepository.findById(nonExistingAppointmentId) >> { throw new AppointmentNotFoundException("Appointment with id " + nonExistingAppointmentId + " not found") }
  findAppointmentQueryHandler.handle(nonExistingAppointmentId)

  then:
  thrown(AppointmentNotFoundException)
}
```

Also this one passed without any problem:

```java
def "should throw AppointmentNotFoundException when appointment do not exist" () {
  given:
  long nonExistingAppointmentId = 69L

  when:
  appointmentRepository.findById(nonExistingAppointmentId) >> { throw new AppointmentNotFoundException("Appointment with id " + nonExistingAppointmentId + " not found") }
  findAppointmentQueryHandler.handle(nonExistingAppointmentId)

  then:
  1 * appointmentRepository.findById(69L)
}
```

But if I try to make 1 test to check all of it then I have error

```java
def "should throw AppointmentNotFoundException when appointment do not exist" () {
  given:
  long nonExistingAppointmentId = 69L

  when:
  appointmentRepository.findById(nonExistingAppointmentId) >> { throw new AppointmentNotFoundException("Appointment with id " + nonExistingAppointmentId + " not found") }
  findAppointmentQueryHandler.handle(nonExistingAppointmentId)

  then:
  1 * appointmentRepository.findById(69L)
  thrown(AppointmentNotFoundException)
}
```

Error:

```
Expected exception of type 'com.bbc.anotherhospital.exceptions.AppointmentNotFoundException', but no exception was thrown
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.checkExceptionThrown(SpecInternals.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.thrownImpl(SpecInternals.java:71)
    at com.bbc.anotherhospital.appointment.handlers.FindAppointmentQueryHandlerSpec.should throw AppointmentNotFoundException when appointment do not exist
```

First I think that I have problem in my code or smth.. But application works fine, tested in Postman.

Anybody have idea why is it behaving this way?

My pom:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.15</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add things so I could run your examples, but does:

```
class TestSpec extends Specification {

    def "should throw AppointmentNotFoundException when appointment do not exist" () {
        given:
        AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository = Mock()
        FindAppointmentQueryHandler findAppointmentQueryHandler = new FindAppointmentQueryHandler(appRepository: appointmentRepository)
        long nonExistingAppointmentId = 69L

        when:
        findAppointmentQueryHandler.handle(nonExistingAppointmentId)

        then:
        def ex = thrown(AppointmentNotFoundException)
        ex.message == "Appointment with id $nonExistingAppointmentId not found"

        1 * appointmentRepository.findById(69L) >> {
            throw new AppointmentNotFoundException("Appointment with id " + nonExistingAppointmentId + " not found")
        }
    }

    static class FindAppointmentQueryHandler {

        AppointmentRepository appRepository

        String handle(long id) {
            appRepository.findById(id)
        }
    }

    static class AppointmentRepository {

        String findById(long id) {
            "called $id"
        }
    }

    static class AppointmentNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

        AppointmentNotFoundException(String message) {
            super(message)
        }
    }
}
```

work?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Spock FAQ, also here on Stack Overflow. The [Spock manual](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) clearly explains, why what you are doing does not work:

> #### Combining Mocking and Stubbing
>
> Mocking and stubbing go hand-in-hand:
>
> ```java
> 1 * subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"
> 1 * subscriber.receive("message2") >> "fail"
> ```
>
> When mocking and stubbing the same method call, they have to happen in the same interaction. In particular, the following Mockito-style splitting of stubbing and mocking into two separate statements will *not* work:
>
> ```java
> given:
> subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"
>
> when:
> publisher.send("message1")
>
> then:
> 1 * subscriber.receive("message1")
> ```
>
> As explained in [Where to Declare Interactions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#_where_to_declare_interactions), the `receive` call will first get matched against the interaction in the `then:` block. Since that interaction doesn't specify a response, the default value for the method's return type (`null` in this case) will be returned. (This is just another facet of Spock's lenient approach to mocking.). Hence, the interaction in the `given:` block will never get a chance to match.
>
> **NOTE:** Mocking and stubbing of the same method call has to happen in the same interaction.

I.e., you want to use something like

```java
1 * appointmentRepository.findById(nonExistingAppointmentId) >> {
  throw new AppointmentNotFoundException("Appointment with id " + nonExistingAppointmentId + " not found")
}
```

in your `then:` block.

Comment: Actually, now I am a little bit angry. My answer is correct, was here first and even explains why it was not working the way you tried. Yesterday, I cloned your repository on commit 9765c936 and changed [this section in `FindAppointmentQueryHandlerSpec`](https://github.com/MichalBarnat/anotherhospital/blob/9765c936fa39e2ee6107444ac4c68596c157eb03/anotherhospital/src/test/java/com/bbc/anotherhospital/appointment/handlers/FindAppointmentQueryHandlerSpec.groovy#L87-L92) exactly the way described above. It fixed the problem. Why did you accept the later answer with the identical solution?

Comment: Here is proof that my solution works in your repository: [changed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3OVl.png), [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHgWT.png).